# Typing a function which takes either a function or a value

Tags: typescript

I want to implement a function which takes a single argument of type T (non callable) or () => T, and returns T.
If this single argument is a function (() => T) then it should return the result of it's invocation. If it's not a function then it should return the argument itself.

I wrote it like this:

```js
function getValue<T>(valueOrThunk: T | (() => T)): T {
    if (typeof valueOrThunk === "function") {
      return valueOrThunk()
    }
    return valueOrThunk
}
```

It works but I get the following TypeScript error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

I don't understand why it says so. How can (T & Function) not have a call signature if Function.prototype has a call method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowing generics is a tricky task for the compiler. If you check the type of the `thunkOrValue` after you check if it is a function you will see `(() => T) | (T & Function)`

The correct approach here is to use *function overloading*:

```
function getValue<T extends () => void>(valueOrThunk: T): ReturnType<T>;
function getValue<T>(valueOrThunk: T): T;
function getValue<T>(valueOrThunk: T): T {
  if (typeof valueOrThunk === 'function') {
    return valueOrThunk();
  }
  return valueOrThunk;
}
```

First comes the most specific overload, which accepts the function and returns its return type, the other one returns what it has received.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUA8AKoqgB5SpgAmAzogBQCUiAvAHyIBucM17DLrnwB5AE5EAFuADWALkREmCgEroQYsEQCeAB0JF2AbgBQoSLAQp02PAYFC74qbIVK3p89HhI0mYfaCAc7SYPKKyoqIAN4miIgwwIxQeqhwSY6iEqEybKysiADkXpZghSyx8fFi6prcwdmyzKbxAL5xiDVQGkiZqCGypu1AA)

Comment: It kind of works, meaning the error fades away, but then I have to cast the result of a function (as T) because this implementation has a signature: `function getValue<T | (() => T)>(valueOrThunk: T | (() => T)): T | (() => T)`

I have rewritten my code as follows:
```typescript
function getValue<T>(valueOrThunk: T | (() => T)): T {
  if (typeof valueOrThunk === "function") {
    return (valueOrThunk as () => T)()
  }
  return valueOrThunk
}

```
And it works but still it feels hacky

Comment: You don't need to add constraints to the implementation. It works as expected [already](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUA8AKoqgB5SpgAmAzogBQCUiAvAHyIBucM17DLrnwB5AE5EAFuADWALkREmCgEroQYsEQCeAB0JF2AbgBQoSLAQp02PAYFC74qbIVK3p89HhI0mYfaCAc7SYPKKyoqIAN4miIgwwIxQeqhwSY6iEqEybKysiADkXpZghSyx8fFi6prcwdmyzKbxAL5xiDVQGkiZqCGypu0mJhAItFCIXmyMLByIAIymJgD0K4hgIAC2AEaoYqPjkzW0IDiTBX62+AxeTEA)

Comment: I mean something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUA8AKoqgB5SpgAmAzogBQCUiAvAHyIBucM17DLrnwB5AE5EAFuADWALkREmCgEroQYsEQCeAB0JF2AbgBQoSLAQp02PAYFC74qbIVK3p89HhI0mYfaCAc7SYPKKyoqIAN4miIgwwIxQeqhwSY6iEqEybKysiADkXpZghSyx8fFi6prcwdmyzKbxAL5xiDVQGkiZqCGypu1m4N5W4ADuYli6tvjEAh19bogAPozMbJxKJpEklZ21vjYBQXYsJu1AA

Comment: You can fix it as it is done in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUA8AKoqgB5SpgAmAzogBQCUiAvAHyIBucM17DLrnwB5AE5EAFuADWALkREmCgEroQYsEQCeAB0JF2AbgBQoSLAQp02PAYFC74qbIVK3p89HhI0mYfaCAc7SYPKKyoqIAN4miIgwwIxQeqhwSY6iEqEybKysiADkXpZghSyx8fFi6prcwdmyzKbxAL5xiDVQGkiZqCGypu0mEAi0UIjgAO5iWLq2+Aop+unW-nZsiMQOAW6IAD6MzGycSiwcMR1dPWsLqEF2TEOmJgD0r0WFI2MTNbQgOAmBWms3mAQYhXKQA)